# Business rules model in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

In general, I am looking a way to model business rules in Enterprise Architect. 
E.g. "Age must be between 18-50","Value cannot be greater than 100".

I am trying to add Business Rules model in Enterprise Architect. According to the instructions on Sparx's website ([manual](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/domain_based_models/business_rule_modeling.html)) it should be available from Model Wizard. Unfortunately, I do not see it in my EA version (12.1.1225 Corporate Edition). I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong or for example, I need to import that model.Perhaps the manual is not up-to-date.

Does anyone know how to add Business rule model in EA? Or knows any other efficient way to store it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Business Rule model is not available in the Corporate Edition.

See the [Sparx Website](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/compare-editions.html) for an overview of the different editions.

Comment: Kamil, if this answers your question can you please accept it (click on the V next to the answer)